# I want to split my minutes, seconds and hundreds to seconds and hundreds

Tags: c#

I want to set a time in minutes to only seconds, does anyone know what's wrong with this code? (time `mm:ss,hh` to `ss,hh`. Example `01:12,10` to `72,10` seconds)

```
public double timeToSeconds(string TimeToSplit)
{
    string[] Timesplitter = new string[2];
    double minutes;
    double seconds;
    Timesplitter = TimeToSplit.Split(':');

    minutes = double.Parse(Timesplitter[0]);        //double with minutes
    seconds = double.Parse(Timesplitter[1]);        //double with seconds
    if (minutes != 0)
    {
        seconds = seconds + (minutes * 60);
    }
    return seconds;
}
```

Comment: This works for me. `timeToSeconds("01:12,10")` returns `72,1` (with a German locale, which uses `,` as the decimal separator).

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: Is the comma an issue maybe??

Comment: The `double.Parse` for the seconds without specifying a culture looks quite dangerous to me.

Comment: Yes. it may be the ',' that causes `double.Parse` to fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should parse your string to a TimeSpan:

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.ParseExact(TimeToSplit, "mm\\:ss\\,ff", provider);

return ts.TotalSeconds
```

Comment: It shold be `"mm\\:ss\\,ff"`.

Comment: OK, no problem. Please don't forget to upvote / accept the answer(s) that have helped you.

Comment: can't upvote, not enough reputation. But accepted your answer

Answer (score 7):

You should use a `TimeSpan`. Here's one way to parse that:

```
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.ParseExact("01:12,10", "mm\\:ss\\,ff", null);
double seconds = ts.TotalSeconds;
return seconds; // it's 72.1
```

Comment: Feels good to finally break that 10K mark doesn't it! Good answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are better working with the DateTime object rather than doubles and using TimeSpans's TotalSeconds

Comment: Actually you would use TimeSpan.

Comment: I know but my project is almost finished so I'd like to end it this way.. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use a comma as the decimal separator of your number. Your code works fine on systems that have a locale that uses a comma for this (for example German); all others will break though, as a comma is a thousands separator there.

You can specify the locale when running `double.Parse`. A possible solution would be to replace the comma by a dot and use an invariant locale:

```
double.Parse(Timesplitter[1].Replace(',', '.'), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

This will allow you to use both dots or commas.

That being said, using TimeSpan as others suggested is definitely the better option.